# PG::SyntaxError when ActiveRecord has default order and sub-scope use union search

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have three models Project, Project::Task, and Project::Task::Video look like following:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tasks
    has_many :videos, class_name: 'Project::Task::Video', through: :tasks
end

class Project::Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    default_scope { order(id: :asc) }
    belongs_to :app
    has_many :videos, source: :videos
end

class Project::Task::Video < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_taggable

    belongs_to :task

    def self.search(keyword)
        result_1 = Project::Task::Video.tagged_with(something)
        result_2 = Project::Task::Video.join(something).where(something)
        total_result = Project::Task::Video.from("(#{result_1.to_sql} UNION #{result_2.to_sql}) AS project_task_videos")
    end
end
```

When I want to do some data searching from database, I wrote following code:

```
app.videos.search('stuff')
```

Then I get error message:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Projects#videos

PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "UNION"
LINE 1: ...deleted_at" IS NULL ORDER BY "project_tasks"."id" ASC UNION SELE...
```

But if I remove default order scope `default_scope { order(id: :asc) }` from Project::Task, these code just work fine.

And the original result sql code combines many joins, so union query is necessarily.

Can I just use default order scope with sub-model union together? or there is other way to make default order for `tasks`?

Please Help me figue it out.

-

Additional Note:
My full sql message has taskitem layer, may looks a little more complicated.

```
: SELECT  "app_task_taskitem_videos".* FROM (SELECT "app_task_taskitem_videos".* FROM "app_task_taskitem_videos" INNER JOIN "app_task_taskitems" ON "app_task_taskitem_videos"."taskitem_id" = "app_task_taskitems"."id" INNER JOIN "app_tasks" ON "app_task_taskitems"."task_id" = "app_tasks"."id" WHERE "app_tasks"."app_id" = 1 AND "app_task_taskitems"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "app_task_taskitems"."deleted_at" IS NULL ORDER BY "app_tasks"."id" ASC UNION SELECT "app_task_taskitem_videos".* FROM "app_task_taskitem_videos" INNER JOIN "app_task_taskitems" ON "app_task_taskitem_videos"."taskitem_id" = "app_task_taskitems"."id" INNER JOIN "app_tasks" ON "app_task_taskitems"."task_id" = "app_tasks"."id" WHERE "app_tasks"."app_id" = 1 AND "app_task_taskitems"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "app_task_taskitems"."deleted_at" IS NULL ORDER BY "app_tasks"."id" ASC) AS app_task_taskitem_videos INNER JOIN "app_task_taskitems" ON "app_task_taskitem_videos"."taskitem_id" = "app_task_taskitems"."id" INNER JOIN "app_tasks" ON "app_task_taskitems"."task_id" = "app_tasks"."id" WHERE "app_tasks"."app_id" = $1 AND "app_task_taskitems"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "app_task_taskitems"."deleted_at" IS NULL ORDER BY "app_tasks"."id" ASC, "app_task_taskitem_videos"."id" DESC LIMIT $2 OFFSET $3
```

Comment: Can you show the SQL statement from logs?

Comment: I added sql statement in origional post. It has a little different with my sample.

Comment: Try this query: `Project::Task::Videos.where(something).or(Project::Task::Videos.where(something))`

Comment: @AshikSalman I use `tagged_with` of `taggable lib` for result_1 and use `join` for result_2. Could you tell me how to combine these with or? (I edited the post for these)

Comment: What error are yo getting now by using (`Query1.or(Query2)`) ?

Comment: @AshikSalman I don't know how to combine `tagged_with ` and  `join` with `or`, could you give me some hint?

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to solve this problem. Just unscope the order of tasks before videos by lambda in `Projects` like following:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tasks
    has_many :videos, -> { unscope(:order) }, class_name: 'Project::Task::Video', through: :tasks
end
```